# Stacktrace for Roslyn Code Fixer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

Is there any way to get a stacktrace from users when a custom code fixer throws an exception?

There is [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2697?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container) open GitHub issue to improve the whole story on this, but it claims that there should be an entry in the activity list with the stack trace.

Running Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 with /log some_file.txt I do not see any applicable entry in the file anywhere when an exception occurs.

Comment: @SLaks Great when debugging on my own, not an option when exceptions happen at some arbitrary users machine.

Comment: Have you looked at `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml`?

Comment: @Jeroen Yep, nothing in there either.

Comment: @Voo oh wait, check `C:\Users\jeroen\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0Roslyn\ActivityLog.xml` instead. You're working in the Roslyn hive

Comment: @Jeroen Oh haven't checked that one, I'll try tomorrow and see if it's in there. Sounds very reasonable for it to be in there.

Comment: @Jeroen That folder only seems to exist if you actually installed the Roslyn SDK (I guess, it's there on my dev install, but not on my reference default installation), which the end users of the code fixer almost certainly haven't.